# CoreData crash with main queue context set as child of private queue context

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, concurrency

My problems goes like this. I want to async saves to disk. The code to setup core data stack looks like this.

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    NSManagedObjectContext *privateMOC = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    [privateMOC setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    __managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    [__managedObjectContext setParentContext:privateMOC];


});
return __managedObjectContext;
}
```

When I perform such fetch:

```
NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:[DataObject entityName]
                                          inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

[request setEntity:entity];
[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(threadEntities, $emp, $emp.thread = %@).@count>0 AND tags.@count!=0", self, nil ]];
[request setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"creationDate", @"data"]];
[request setSortDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:YES]]];
NSError *error = nil;

[result addObjectsFromArray:[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error]];
```

it crashes with this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 375961053 beyond bounds [0 .. 7]'
```

On the other hand stack setup like this works perfectly well:

```
  - (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    __managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    [__managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
});
return __managedObjectContext;
}
```

Database has inside one DataObject and some additional objects used to manage it around. The question is, why this fetch is affected, while a count that app does before with same parameters works both times?

Comment: What irritates me a little bit is that `privateMOC` goes out of scope after the creation of `__managedObjectContext`. I don't know if a MOC keeps a strong reference to it parent context. If not, then the private context could be deallocated and then strange things happen. - You could try to keep a strong reference to `privateMOC` in an instance variable and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like something inside CoreData is getting inconsistent, as if you were also processing a bad merge notification (which you shouldn't have to do when using parent child, and should not attempt!). Without a full stack trace unfortunately it would be pretty difficult to reconstruct what was going on here.

However I don't see a *reason* to set up your main queue context inside the dispatch_once block. Contexts are made to be cheap, there is no reason not to produce a new child context every time you need one - and that is the recommended way to use them. An [NSManagedObjectContext](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html)is:

> An instance of NSManagedObjectContext represents a single “object
>   space” or scratch pad in an application. Its primary responsibility is
>   to manage a collection of managed objects. These objects form a group
>   of related model objects that represent an internally consistent view
>   of one or more persistent stores.

And with [parent-child](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-CoreData/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010637):

> When you save changes in a context, the changes are only committed
>   “one store up.” If you save a child context, changes are pushed to its
>   parent. These changes are not saved to the persistent store until the
>   root context is saved. (A root managed object context is one whose
>   parent is nil.) In addition, a parent does not pull changes from
>   children before it saves. You must save a child contexts if you want
>   ultimately to commit the changes.
>
> Nested contexts make it more important than ever that you adopt the
>   “pass the baton” approach of accessing a context (by passing a context
>   from one view controller to the next) rather than retrieving it
>   directly from the application delegate.

If you want to see a simple example of setting up parent-child contexts and using queue confinement:
https://github.com/quellish/QueuedCoreData