# Managed Object Context is nil for some reason in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, alamofire

I'm using Alamofire to submit a request to an endpoint using Swift.  I parse the JSON objects that I receive from the response using the Codable protocol, and then try to insert the objects into Core Data using Managed Object Subclasses.

However, when I do this, I keep receiving an error saying that my parent Managed Object Context (MOC) is nil.  This doesn't make sense to me because I set the MOC via Dependency Injection from the AppDelegate, and confirm that it has a value by printing out it's value to the console in the viewDidLoad() method.

Here is my relevant code:

I set my MOC here:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext! {
    didSet {
        print("moc set")
    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(managedObjectContext)
}
```

///

```
func registerUser(userID: String, password: String) {
    
    let parameters: [String: Any] = ["email": userID, "password": password, "domain_id": 1]
    let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Accept": "application/json"]
    
    Alamofire.request(registerURL, method: .patch, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
        
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            
            if let value = response.result.value {
                print(value)
                let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
                
                do {
                    let jsonData = try jsonDecoder.decode(JSONData.self, from: response.data!)
                    print(jsonData.data.userName)
                    print(jsonData.data.identifier)
                    print(self.managedObjectContext)
                    
                    let privateContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
                    privateContext.parent = self.managedObjectContext
                    
                    let user = UserLogin(context: privateContext)
                    user.userName = jsonData.data.userName
                    user.domainID = Int16(jsonData.data.identifier)
                    user.password = "blah"
                    
                    do {
                        try privateContext.save()
                        try privateContext.parent?.save()
                    } catch let saveErr {
                        print("Failed to save user", saveErr)
                    }
                    
                } catch let jsonDecodeErr{
                    print("Failed to decode", jsonDecodeErr)
                }
                
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

The specific error message I'm getting is:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Parent NSManagedObjectContext must not be nil.'
```

I realize that Alamofire is download the data on a background thread, which is why I use a child context, but I'm not sure why the parent is nil.

Here is the setup code for my Managed Object Context:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer!
var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    
    createContainer { container in
        
        self.persistentContainer = container
        let storyboard = self.window?.rootViewController?.storyboard
        guard let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RootViewController") as? ViewController else { fatalError("Cannot instantiate root view controller")}
        vc.managedObjectContext = container.viewContext
        self.window?.rootViewController = vc
        
    }
    
    return true
}

func createContainer(completion: @escaping(NSPersistentContainer) -> ()) {
    
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Test")
    container.loadPersistentStores { _, error in
        
        guard error == nil else { fatalError("Failed to load store: \(error!)") }
        DispatchQueue.main.async { completion(container) }
        
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you post your setup parent NSManagedObjectContext code?

Comment: @QuocNguyen done.

Comment: I see some suggestion here. Did you check it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13646696/coredata-crash-with-main-queue-context-set-as-child-of-private-queue-context

Comment: Unfortunately that suggestion is not helpful to my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything immediately "wrong" so lets debug this a bit.

1. Put a breakpoint in `applicationDidFinish...` right after the guard.
2. Put a breakpoint at the creation of the `privateContext`.

Which fires first?

Where is the `registerUser` function?  In a view controller? I hope not :)

> the breakpoint right after my guard statement fires first. And yes, my registerUser function is indeed inside a ViewController.

Putting network code in view controllers is a code smell.  View Controllers have one job, manage their views.  Data gathering belongs in a persistence controller; for example, extending your `NSPersistentContainer` and putting data collection code there.

However, that is not the issue here, just a code smell.

Next test.

Is your persistent container and/or viewContext being passed into your view controller and bring retained?

Is your view controller being destroyed before the block fires?

To test this, I would put an assertion before `Alamofire.request` and crash if the context is `nil`:

```
NSAssert(self.managedObjectContext != nil, @"Main context is nil in the view controller");
```

I would also put that same line of code just before:

```
privateContext.parent = self.managedObjectContext
```

Run again. What happens?

> I ran the test as you described, and I get the error: Thread 1: Assertion failed: Main context is nil in the view controller

Which assertion crashed? (probably should change the text a bit...)

If it is the first one then your view controller is not receiving the `viewContext`.

If it is the second one then the `viewContext` is going back to `nil` before the block executes.

Change your assumptions accordingly.

> discovered something that is relevant here: If I place a button to call the registerUser() function at the user's discretion instead of calling it directly from the viewDidLoad() method, there is no crash, the code runs fine, and the MOC has a value

That leads me down the theory that your `registerUser()` was being called before your `viewDidLoad()`. You can test that by putting a break point in both and see which one fires first.  If your `registerUser()` fires first, look at the stack and see what is calling it.

If it fires *after* your `viewDidLoad()` then put a breakpoint on the context property and see what is setting it back to `nil`.

> So if I remove that line, how do I set the MOC property on my RootViewController via Dependency Injection?

The line right before it is the clue here.

```
let storyboard = self.window?.rootViewController?.storyboard
```

Here you are getting a reference to the `storyboard` from the `rootViewController` which is already instantiated and associated with the `window` of your application.

Therefore you could change the logic to:

```
(self.window?.rootViewController as? ViewController).managedObjectContext = container.viewContext
```

Although I would clean that up and put some `nil` logic around it :)

> The problem I realize is that the MOC in the `RootViewController` is being used BEFORE the MOC is returned from the closure, and set in the `AppDelegate`. What do I do here?

This is a common synchronous (UI) vs. asynchronous (persistence) issue.  Ideally your UI should wait until the persistence loads.  If you load the persistent stores and then finish the UI after the stores have loaded it will resolve this issue.

Without a migration we are generally talking ms here rather than seconds.

BUT ... You want the same code to handle the UI loading whether it is milliseconds or seconds. How you solve that is up to you (design decision).  One example is to continue the loading view until the persistence layer is ready and then transition over.

If you did that you could then subtly change the loading view if a migration is happening to inform the user as to why things are taking so long.

Comment: Thanks so much for your prompt reply!  I did as you asked, and the breakpoint right after my guard statement fires first.

And yes, my registerUser function is indeed inside a ViewController.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with doing unit tests (one of the many areas I need to build in my portfolio), but I do believe the issue that you just raised is in fact the problem.  Is there another way for me to check this?

Comment: I ran the test as you described, and I get the error: 

Thread 1: Assertion failed: Main context is nil in the view controller

Comment: My assertion before my Alamofire.request is fired, crashes.

Comment: To respond to your point above, "If it is the first one then your view controller is not receiving the viewContext", however, if you notice, I have a property observer for my MOC, as well as a print statement in my viewDidLoad() method, and in each case, I do get a print out to my console with the reference to the MOC.  The interesting thing is that it seems that it appears that the MOC is set, and then later becomes nil.  Does this make sense?

Comment: I discovered something that is relevant here:  If I place a button to call the registerUser() function at the user's discretion instead of calling it directly from the viewDidLoad() method, there is no crash, the code runs fine, and the MOC has a value.  Why?

Comment: So the registerUser() function is being called AFTER viewDidLoad().  So what you're saying is, place a breakpoint on the MOC property INSIDE the registerUser() function and discover what is setting it to nil.  How do I determine what is setting it to nil?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the property (the var) itself, not in any function.  Putting a breakpoint on the `var` will show you who touches it and when.  That will show you when it is getting set back to `nil`.

Comment: The thing is, this is simply a test app where the ViewController where everything happens is the RootViewController of the project, which means the viewDidLoad() method is called right away from the start.  When I slowly step through the code, I notice that my code works.  Does this mean that there is some kind of "race condition"?

Comment: Yes, that is what appears to be going on.  The construction of your `createContainer` is async so you are in the land of threads here :)

Comment: So would using perform or performBlock help?

Comment: Your are creating an instance of your root vc in code, but is the system also intstantiating one for you automatically? If you are handling the instantiating of your root, make sure your project is set to not use a storyboard. Otherwise you will be creating two - the first, created by the storyboard, Will have a nil moc. The second one which your are creating, is replacing the first and has an moc. But by then the damage has been done.

Comment: @JasonC.Howlin That is what is happening.  I believe what you're saying is correct because in my console, I see the print statements in my console occurring twice (and I wondered why).  How do I resolve this?

Comment: Excellent catch by @JasonC.Howlin!  Since you are creating your UI twice you need to remove one of them.  Either stop using the storyboard or stop instantiating the UI manually.  I suspect removing `guard let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RootViewController") as? ViewController else { fatalError("Cannot instantiate root view controller")}` will be a good start.

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra So if I remove that line, how do I set the MOC property on my RootViewController via Dependency Injection?

Comment: I've made the changes you pointed out, and am now using the line:

(self.window?.rootViewController as? ViewController).managedObjectContext = container.viewContext

however, I'm still getting an error because it's trying to unwrap an optional which is nil.  The problem I realize is that the MOC in the RootViewController is being used BEFORE the MOC is returned from the closure, and set in the AppDelegate.  What do I do here?