# Coredata crash dispose object : -[NSManagedObjectContext _dispose:]

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Hi we are getting the frequent crash related with Core data managed object context in production and which is not replicate on our end, and we got stuck what to do.

The stack trace is below:

```
Crashed: NSManagedObjectContext 0x2807e5ad0
0  CoreData                       0x380ec -[NSManagedObjectContext _dispose:] + 488
1  CoreData                       0x43184 -[NSManagedObjectContext _dealloc__] + 648
2  CoreData                       0x49220 __internalBlockToDeallocNSManagedObjectContext_block_invoke + 52
3  CoreData                       0x22dac developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 148
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x642f0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
5  libdispatch.dylib              0xa54c _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 644
6  libdispatch.dylib              0xaff0 _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 408
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x14ae4 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 632
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xf38 _pthread_wqthread + 284
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xaa4 start_wqthread + 8
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5tOC.png)

Answer (score 1):

Core Data crashes can occur when doing modifications on different threads or contexts.

[Here's an article](https://www.avanderlee.com/debugging/core-data-debugging-xcode/) about debugging these issues.

[Here's an SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19352490/1971013) about context issues.

Comment: I followed this links already

Comment: @AshishGore did you see any warnings printed when switching on CoreData debug?  There is something wrong in your code, that 100% sure.  Did you thoroughly evaluate all CoreData code for these issues?